# Activity diagram for Login use-case

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I made this activity diagram for `Login` use case of an IS. I've tried to cover all possible outcomes(login successful, wrong username/password, forgotten password), but I don't know if I've done it correctly. What do you think?

[image: Activity diagram for login use case]

Comment: After sending new password, you should redirect user back to the login page.

Comment: @MaxZoom That was one of the thoughts, but then again if user gets new password by email, isn't that end of activity because user goes away from login page to his email provider?

Comment: I would say no, because sending new password is part of the login activity, which continue on the login page.

Comment: Besides the fact that `Login` is no use case but an activity, there is no time out handling. Further: without requirements, this is a purely opinion based question.